# Distribuição eletrônica em PHP sem passar do limite de eletróns

Tags: php

Estou querendo criar um programinha que faz a distribuição eletrônica de acordo com o diagrama de Pauling.
Antes de começar, eu tenho uma dúvida:

Como posso limitar, em PHP, a quantidade de eletróns que cada subnível pode ter?

Exemplo: Subnível "s" o máximo de elétrons é 2 (Mas pode ter menos que isso), subnível "p" o máximo de elétrons é 6 (Mas pode ter menos que isso), etc...

Tem como eu fazer esse limite?

Comment: Você vai ter que fazer uma [Árvore binária](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria), onde cada nível da árvore (nodo) você define a quantidade máxima de elétrons. conforme você vai entrando nos subníveis da árvore, você vai tratando.

Comment: São 4 os subniveis não? s p d  r, respectivamente 2 6 10  14, certo? Então como você pega esses subniveis no PHP?